# google plus login vs google login, whats the difference?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-signin

I need to develop a web app so that google users can login via google APIs(OAuth2). One thing that I dont understand is that why google has separated googlePlus login from google login?
Isnt it that if someone has a Google plug(G+) account he definitely has a google account too?

Comment: Today. Google notified me that g+ sign in is deprecated, and needs to be migrated to google sign in. Then I realize that they are different :). There is also firebase login... C'on google, please dont  do that

Comment: Somehow google thinks people in the world are all smart as their developers and they always make things over complicated

Answer (score 0):

Google+ login also uses gmail id like Google login, but difference is in the protocols they use to authenticate users.
Google+ login is based on OpenId Connect protocol which is a layer over OAuth2.0 while old version i.e Google login supports Open Id 2.0 which is now deprecated by Google.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Google+ supersedes Google sign-in where the prior has a much richer offering in terms of the data it can retrieve.

To answer your question regarding if someone has google plus account automatically has Google; the answer is yes but the method which one uses to authenticate and the data richness of the data that can be retrieved is currently different.

If you are looking to implement a sign-in feature on your application I would recommend looking at the Google+ developer guide.